# How to create step function (executes next step then stops) using Action Script?

Tags: actionscript-2

I want to create a step function which when pressed executes the next step and then stops.
I've written this code on a simple button in AS2.

`on(release){var test:Number = currentFrame;
_root.gotoAndPlay(++test);
_root.stop();
}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you could write it this way :

```
on(release){
  _root.gotoAndStop(_root.currentFrame + 1);
}
```